# Stratified svyglm in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survey

I'm looking for advice on how to conduct a weighted logistic regression analysis, stratified by gender, in R.

For my main, unstratified analysis, I generated inverse probability weights (invp) and ran a weighted logistic regression as follows:

```
complete_cases_weighted <- svydesign(id=~1, weights=~invp, data=complete_cases)
svyglm(outcome ~ exposure, design=complete_cases_weighted, family="binomial")
```

I now want to essentially re-run this analysis twice, once for females only, and once for males only.

What's the best way of doing this with correct weighting? Do I re-do the entire process of generating weights and running a weighted logistic regression having subset my data into males and females? Or is there some fancy footwork I can do with `svydesign`/`svyglm` to do this?

Comment: this seems like a stats question so it might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - I'm clear on the statistics behind this, I'm purely trying to understand the best way to code this in R. In essence, whether I have to repeat the existing weight generation and analysis code on subsets of the data, or whether `svydesign` and `svyglm` have built-in features which handle this.

Answer (score 2):

from `?svyglm`

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
summary(svyglm(api00~ell+meals+mobility, design=dstrat))
```

loop through all levels of `sch.wide`

```
for( this_value in unique( apistrat$sch.wide ) ){

    print( this_value )
    print( summary(svyglm(api00~ell+meals+mobility, design=subset(dstrat,sch.wide== this_value ))))

}
```

Comment: a great solution. Thank you for explaining the nuances of working with subsets. Only it's strange that it doesn't match the results `svyby(formula = api00 ~ ell + meals + mobility, by = ~ sch.wide, design = dstrat, FUN = svyglm)`

Comment: @YuriySaraykin yep, the `svyby` output is more condensed